# HTML5 Canvas: Drawing a single line causes visual bug

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm working on a map editor/ line of sight calculator for an online game using an "infinite" canvas that the user can scroll. My goal is to draw a line from a player's position (currently static) to the cursor position. So far, I can draw the line just fine, but when I scroll the canvas just far enough, I get a pretty bad visual bug. It appears as if the `draw()` function is no longer clearing the screen correctly. I can confirm that the line is the culprit by removing that block of code.

My (stripped down) `drawLine()` function:

```
function drawLine() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(150, 300);
    context.lineTo(Mouse.x, -Mouse.y);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
}
```

My `draw()` function (variable `grid` is just a repeating pattern):

```
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(-translatedX, -translatedY, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    context.rect(-window.innerWidth, -window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth * 2, window.innerHeight * 2);
    context.fillStyle = grid;
    context.fill();
}
```

And my `pan()` function that triggers onmouseove:

```
function pan(e) {
    var evt = e || event;

    if(dragging == true) {
        deltaX = evt.offsetX - lastX;
        deltaY = evt.offsetY - lastY;
        translatedX += deltaX;
        translatedY += deltaY;
        context.translate(deltaX, -deltaY);
        lastX = evt.offsetX;
        lastY = evt.offsetY;
    }

    Mouse = {
        x: evt.offsetX - (window.innerWidth / 2 + translatedX),
        y: evt.offsetY - (window.innerHeight / 2 + translatedY)
    }

    draw();
}
```

*If any more information is required, I will be happy to supply.*

**EDIT:** Updated with screenshot and link:

http://iamchristopher.ca/editor/

[image: Canvas drawing bug]

Comment: I would suspect that you are drawing on part of the canvas that you are not clearing with `clearRect`. This is called the hall of mirrors effect, and is caused by not clearing all of the screen between frames, but not drawing over all of it either: http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Hall_of_mirrors_effect

Comment: @Patashu Very interesting. Any idea why my line would prevent the screen from clearing properly? As I mentioned, everything is fine if I take that block of code out.

Comment: I suspect that your call to `clearRect` covers a smaller area than your call to `rect`. That is what I would look at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working away at this problem and I think I've found a solution. I still don't know *why* my line was causing the issue, but the answer was the modify the `context.rect()` to include the translated coordinates:

```
context.rect(-window.innerWidth - translatedX, -window.innerHeight + translatedY, window.innerWidth * 2, window.innerHeight * 2);
```

Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks again to @Patashu.